# How can I create a number input that always pads to 2 digits?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two `type="number"` `<input>` elements, which I want to use to let people enter the *hours* and *minutes* parts of a time value in a mobile application.

By default, the two input element's value is `0`, so they both show `0`. This results in a display of `0:0`. The usual representation however would be `0:00`, so I would want the second input to show double digits.

Also, if the user enters a value below 10, I would still want the input to show the number padded with a `0`.

I could imagine a couple of ways to do this with a text input field, but that would create the problem of validation. Also, I picked `type="number"` specifically, so the mobile OS will pop open the numeric input when the `input` element is focused.

Comment: How about `type="time"`?

Comment: @Juhana I had no idea that exists. I would have to check if it's supported on all our deployment targets. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these code for number pad :-

```
function pad(n, width, z)
{
     z = z || '0';
     n = n + '';
     return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
}

pad(10, 4);      // 0010
pad(9, 4);       // 0009
pad(123, 4);     // 0123
```

Comment: That won't work. I can't set the value of a number input to a string.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but those are still strings. The key part about my question is not how to pad a number, but how to achieve the padding in a number input HTML element.